# Angular - Retry failed requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, token

We are implementing a token authorization with refresh token logic our application. Basically, everything works. But we want to retry requests that fail because of a token expiration. Everything is done in the Interceptor. Here is some relevant code:

```
a.service('APIInterceptor', function ($q, $rootScope, $location, $window,    $injector) {
var service = this;
var $http;
var refreshTokenInProcess = false;

executeRequest = function (config) {
    var accessToken = $window.localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (accessToken != 'null') {
        config.headers.authorization = "bearer " + accessToken;
    }
    lastRequest = config;
    return config;
};
service.request = function (config) {
    return executeRequest(config);
};
var tokenRefreshing = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    // Run refresh token service only once in case multiple requests are failing
    if (refreshTokenInProcess == false) {
        var refreshToken = $window.localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');
        var clientId = $window.localStorage.getItem('client_id');
        var apiUrl = $window.localStorage.getItem('apiUrl');

        var param = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" + refreshToken + "&client_id=" + clientId;
        $http = $http || $injector.get('$http');
        $http.post(apiUrl + 'token', param, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }).
        then(function (success) {
            $window.localStorage.setItem('token', success.data.access_token);
            $window.localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', success.data.refresh_token);
            $window.localStorage.setItem('client_id', "web");
            $window.localStorage.setItem('expires', success.data[".expires"]);
            deferred.resolve(success);
            refreshTokenInProcess = false;
        }, function (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        });
    }
    else
        deferred.resolve();
    refreshTokenInProcess = true;
    return deferred.promise;
};
service.responseError = function (response) {
    if (response.status === 406 && response.data === "Unauthenticated Token.") {
            //retry logic
            tokenRefreshing().then(function () {
                return $http(executeRequest(response.config)).then(function (data) {
                    if (data)
                        response.config.callerController(data.data);
                })
            });
    }
};
```

Everything seems to work ok when there is only one failed request, but with two if I wait long enough (like overnight) I see that retrying gets in to a loop. I am trying to flag token refresh with refreshTokenInProcess, but still see that each failed request gets the token refresh.

Give me please some ideas/design patterns for this task.

Thanks

Comment: Probably not the root of your problem, but is the token refresh call succeeding? - if it fails, you aren't resetting `refreshTokenInProcess` to `false`, so retries won't actually call the token and will get stuck in a loop. Also be aware the token refresh call will go through the interceptor as well

Answer (score 0):

Here is a view of my compiled JavaScript, I used TypeScript and provided that code as well.  In general, I would suggest 2 additional patterns:

1. Store the 'refreshTokenInProcess' as a local storage variable in additional to a class variable.  This would help keep a singular persisted value to indicate if the refresh is in process.
2. Track a retryCount and maxRetryCount to make sure a loop does not occur.  You can also perform some other task if the retry count is exceeded.  After a successful refresh the retryCount is reset.

**JavaScript**

```
var TestServices = /** @class */ (function () {
    function TestServices($window, $injector, $http, $q) {
        var _this = this;
        this.$window = $window;
        this.$injector = $injector;
        this.$http = $http;
        this.$q = $q;
        this.tokenRefreshing = function () {
            var deferred = _this.$q.defer();
            // Run refresh token service only once in case multiple requests are failing
            _this.retryCount++;
            var refreshToken = _this.$window.localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');
            var clientId = _this.$window.localStorage.getItem('client_id');
            var apiUrl = _this.$window.localStorage.getItem('apiUrl');
            var param = 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=' + refreshToken + '&client_id=' + clientId;
            _this.$http = _this.$http || _this.$injector.get('$http');
            _this.$http.post(apiUrl + 'token', param, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }).
                then(function (success) {
                _this.$window.localStorage.setItem('token', success.data.access_token);
                _this.$window.localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', success.data.refresh_token);
                _this.$window.localStorage.setItem('client_id', 'web');
                _this.$window.localStorage.setItem('expires', success.data['.expires']);
                _this.refreshTokenInProcess = false;
                // reset the retry count
                _this.retryCount = 0;
                deferred.resolve(success);
            }, function (err) {
                _this.refreshTokenInProcess = false;
                deferred.reject(err);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        };
    }
    Object.defineProperty(TestServices.prototype, "refreshTokenInProcess", {
        get: function () {
            if (this.$window) {
                this._refreshTokenInProcess = this.$window.localStorage.getItem('refreshTokenInProcess') === 'true';
            }
            return this._refreshTokenInProcess === true;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            this._refreshTokenInProcess = value === true;
            var strValue = value === true ? 'true' : 'false';
            if (this.$window) {
                this.$window.localStorage.setItem('refreshTokenInProcess', strValue);
            }
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    TestServices.prototype.executeRequest = function (config) {
        var accessToken = this.$window.localStorage.getItem('token');
        if (accessToken !== 'null') {
            config.headers.authorization = 'bearer ' + accessToken;
        }
        this.lastRequest = config;
        return config;
    };
    TestServices.prototype.request = function (config) {
        return this.executeRequest(config);
    };
    TestServices.prototype.responseError = function (response) {
        var _this = this;
        if (response.status === 406 && response.data === 'Unauthenticated Token.') {
            // retry logic
            if (this.refreshTokenInProcess === false && this.retryCount < this.maxRetryCount) {
                this.refreshTokenInProcess = true;
                this.tokenRefreshing().then(function () {
                    return _this.$http(_this.executeRequest(response.config)).then(function (data) {
                        if (data) {
                            response.config.callerController(data.data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
        return response;
    };
    return TestServices;
}());
```

**TypeScript**

```
export class TestServices implements ng.IHttpInterceptor {

    private _refreshTokenInProcess: boolean;

    get refreshTokenInProcess(): boolean {

        if (this.$window) {
            this._refreshTokenInProcess = this.$window.localStorage.getItem('refreshTokenInProcess') === 'true';
        }
        return this._refreshTokenInProcess === true;
    }
    set refreshTokenInProcess(value: boolean) {
        this._refreshTokenInProcess = value === true;
        const strValue = value === true ? 'true' : 'false';
        if (this.$window) {
            this.$window.localStorage.setItem('refreshTokenInProcess', strValue);
        }
    }

    lastRequest: any;
    maxRetryCount: 10;
    retryCount: 0;

    constructor(public $window: ng.IWindowService, public $injector: ng.auto.IInjectorService, public $http: ng.IHttpService, public $q: ng.IQService) {

    }

    executeRequest(config: ng.IRequestConfig) {
        const accessToken = this.$window.localStorage.getItem('token');
        if (accessToken !== 'null') {
            config.headers.authorization = 'bearer ' + accessToken;
        }
        this.lastRequest = config;
        return config;
    }

    request(config: ng.IRequestConfig) {
        return this.executeRequest(config);
    }

    tokenRefreshing = () => {
        const deferred = this.$q.defer();
        // Run refresh token service only once in case multiple requests are failing
        this.retryCount++;
        const refreshToken = this.$window.localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');
        const clientId = this.$window.localStorage.getItem('client_id');
        const apiUrl = this.$window.localStorage.getItem('apiUrl');

        const param = 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=' + refreshToken + '&client_id=' + clientId;
        this.$http = this.$http || this.$injector.get('$http');
        this.$http.post(apiUrl + 'token', param, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }).
            then((success: any) => {
                this.$window.localStorage.setItem('token', success.data.access_token);
                this.$window.localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', success.data.refresh_token);
                this.$window.localStorage.setItem('client_id', 'web');
                this.$window.localStorage.setItem('expires', success.data['.expires']);
                this.refreshTokenInProcess = false;
                // reset the retry count
                this.retryCount = 0;
                deferred.resolve(success);
            }, (err: any) => {
                this.refreshTokenInProcess = false;
                deferred.reject(err);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    responseError(response: any) {
        if (response.status === 406 && response.data === 'Unauthenticated Token.') {
            // retry logic
            if (this.refreshTokenInProcess === false && this.retryCount < this.maxRetryCount) {
                this.refreshTokenInProcess = true;
                this.tokenRefreshing().then(() => {
                    return this.$http(this.executeRequest(response.config)).then((data: any) => {
                        if (data) {
                            response.config.callerController(data.data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will look into your comments.